# Buildfire - How to allow control side to ban users?

Tags: buildfire

I am developing a social plugin that allows users to post content. On the control side, I plan to display the users' posts and allow the admin to ban users if they post inappropriate content. Is there a way to do this with `buildfire.auth` or something else built into buildfire?

Answer (score 0):

As of this date:
At the plugin-level, you dont have permissions to ban a user at the app-level. However, you may implement logic to ban them at the plugin-level using your own custom logic.